# App Hangs when saving in core data

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm using swift core data to save user's info within the app but when its saving current users data (name,bio, 3-4 photos) it hangs for 2-3 seconds until it saves the data. What is the best way to avoid this hanging of the app? this is the code I'm using

```
       for photo in photos {
            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: photo.url!)!)
            let newimg = UIImage(data: data!)
            newusersImages.addObject(newimg!)
        }

        mayBeUser.name = currentuser!.objectForKey("name") as! String
        let arrayData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(newusersImages)
        let locationData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(currentuser!.objectForKey("location")!)


        mayBeUser.photos = arrayData
        mayBeUser.location = locationData
        mayBeUser.about = currentuser!.objectForKey("about") as! String
        mayBeUser.setValue(currentuser!.objectForKey("age") as! Int, forKey: "age")
        mayBeUser.objectId = currentuser!.objectId!
        mayBeUser.lastSeen = currentuser!.objectForKey("lastSeen") as! NSDate

        try! context.save()
        print("Current User Updated")
```

when the user has 10-15 friends , it takes hangs for a minute to save/update all the info/data of the users.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it. Now obviously you don't want the UI to hang, so you'll want to use a managed object context that has a private queue concurrency type. More info on that [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/113489/core-data-tutorial-multiple-managed-object-contexts). Specifically, look at the part at the end where he details how to create the export function.

Now, since you're saving data to the persistent store in this case, you might not want the user to go around changing stuff while their previous changes are being saved, in this case you might want an interim screen showing the progress of the save.

Comment: yes that can be done but i dont want users to wait for a minute. thats what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You (and your app) are having to work hard to save all that photo data into one attribute of your `User` entity.  Instead, restructure your data model:

1. Create a separate `Photo` entity for the photos.
2. Don't store the photo image data in CoreData - just store a string with the URL.
3. Add a to-many relationship from `User` to `Photo`, instead of the `photos` attribute.

Incidentally, I would avoid using `objectId` as an attribute name: it's so close to CoreData's `objectID` it will cause confusion.

Comment: this doesn't help much actually, should i move to sqlite instead?

Comment: @user528432 If it's still taking 2-3 seconds, I doubt the problem is in the CoreData save.  Have you tried profiling in instruments to see what's taking the time?